# Remove the default message after signing offline mode

Tags: docusignapi

We're using offline mode to sign documents. After signing this message shows up. Can we remove it and how to do it via code? We're using the code in the sample app here https://github.com/docusign/sample-app-tgk-financial-ios, and it  doesn't have this message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to disable it.

```
            var configurations = DSMManager.defaultConfigurations()
            configurations[DSM_SETUP_OFFLINE_SIGNING_HIDE_ALERTS_KEY] = DSM_SETUP_TRUE_VALUE
            DSMManager.setup(withConfiguration: configurations)
```